# PrimeNG patchValue for autocomplete

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am trying to assign a value dynamically to auto-complete but it is not working

**HTML**

```
<label for="centerId" class="control-label">Center</label>
                                    <p-autoComplete formControlName="center" id="centerId"  [suggestions]="iCenter" placeholder="Center (required)" (completeMethod)="searchCC($event)" [style]="{'width':'85%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'85%'}" field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>
```

**interface**

```
export interface ICenter{

   id: string,
   name: string
}
```

**ts**

> (for field="name" dataKey="id" the value is the same, so id=name)

```
iCenter: ICenter[];

also confirmed there is a value 
console.log(this.center)
    searchCC(event) {

    this.iCenter = this.iCenter
        .filter(data => data.name.toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(event.query.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1);

}
 this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
        center: ['', Validators.required],
    });

 this.ersaForm.patchValue({

            //also tried  center:center
          //also tried center: [itimData.center, itimData.center],
            center: [{ 'field': this.center,'dataKey': this.center}],
            phone: itimData.phone,
            email: itimData.email
        });
```

***************************************UPDATE*****************************************************************
Got it working , here is how

center: {id: itimData.center, name: itimData.center },

Comment: Bad tagging, please correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties 'field' and 'dataKey' are not necessarily part of your object.

PrimeNG docs:

**field**

> Field of a suggested object to resolve and display.

**dataKey**

> A property to uniquely identify a value in options.

If your list looks like this:

```
const items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Banana'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Pineapple'}
];
```

Then the property **'field' should refer to 'name'** and **'dataKey' to 'id'**.

Now if you want to set the value of the autocomplete to 'Pineapple' then patchValue looks like this.

```
this.form.patchValue({
    item: {
        id: 3, // mandatory
        name: 'Pineapple' // optional
    }
});
```

The PrimeNG component will search for an object with the id equal to 3. When there is a match he will set the selection to that object.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

Comment: updated my above code. (original post & update section)I am using interface                   this.iCenter:{id: itimData.center, name: itimData.center }, it does not work..see original post

Comment: i should have something like this center:{ 'id': itimData.center, 'cost_name': itimData.center },

Comment: also tried             center: [this.iCenter = [{  id: itimData.center, name: itimData.center }]], no errors but nothing happened

Comment: updated my code above.fixed the issue but another function broke

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's broken now? If it has nothing to do with this issue, it may be a good idea to create another question.

Comment: updated my above code...according to the documents you bind autocomplete to an object like this:    iCenter: ICenter[];
    originalCenter: ICenter[] so i cant do iCenter:{id:1, name'john'} inside the ersaForm.patcValue

Comment: got it working, had other issues that were causing it not to work

Comment: marked it as an answer...since you put me in the right direction :)